# Reference to array of foreign keys jetbrains.exposed.sql

Tags: sql, kotlin, jetbrains-ide, ktor, kotlin-exposed

I have table song and table genre. Song can contains more genres. So I want reference genreIds from table genre. How I can reference to array of foreign keys in jetbrains.exposed.sql? 
For single reference is syntax `(integer("genre_id") references GenreTable.id)`. Any idea?

```
object SongTable : Table() {
    val id       = integer("id").primaryKey().autoIncrement()
    val name     = text("name")
    val genreIds = (integer("genre_id") references GenreTable.id) //THERE I WANT MORE IDS 
}

object GenreTable : Table() {
    val id    = integer("id").primaryKey().autoIncrement()
    val logo  = text("logo")
}
```

Comment: If your goal is unclear to us but we think this link might help
[LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47659975/inserting-and-querying-data-from-table-with-foreign-key-in-sqlite)

Comment: Andrey Tarashevskiy 
You need an additional table to link many-to-many (songs-to-genres)
https://github.com/JetBrains/Exposed/wiki/DAO#many-to-many-reference